# Security for files in android

Tags: android, performance, security, zip, android-internal-storage

I am developing an application in which I need to download some files and secure them so that user can't see the files.
right now I am using dot prefix method to hide files and saving the zip with password protection, however, extracting the zip to use files takes a long time. Is there any way to implement security for saving raw files in internal storage in android

Comment: Add some code here what you actually tried  .

Comment: You cannot protect files on a rooted device.  On a non-rooted device you can store them in internal memory and nothing but your app will have access.

Comment: @nasch thanks for suggestion but please explain how do i do it

Comment: @amitsharma I am just renaming the folder with . (Dot) prefix such as .foldername so it will be hidden from the user and  setting a password to zip file, thats it.

Comment: I'm sure if you search the web for how to write files to internal storage you'll find plenty of resources. It's well documented.